# Prioritize Facebook privacy between lists that are locked and not locked

Tags: facebook, privacy

I can set privacy settings no problem but I cannot find any reference to priority of privacy settings in Facebook.

That is, I have someone in a locked down list I also want to add them to a non-locked down list but still keep them locked down. It is more for me filtering items than anything.

Basically, I play a Facebook game and I have a list that blocks all my information. Now, an actual friend plays the game and I want them to be in the list but I want to make sure I won't be hiding all my info.

Comment: Could you explain further? For example a specific use case?

Comment: Basically I play a Facebook game so I have a list that blocks all my information now and actual friend plays the game and I want them to be in the list but I want to make sure I won't be hiding all my info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did some testing and if you create a list with limited view to your profile and add someone to that list it will take the most restricted view if you then add them to a more open list.
ie

List 1 cant see your email address
List 2 can see your email address

if someone was in both lists they would not see the email address

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I get your situation but here is how I think the priority goes.

For filtering
1. Edit Your News Feed Settings : Hide posts from friends (there is no "Hide posts from lists")
2. Friend Lists

For posting
 1. Visible to individual
 2. Not visible to individual
 3. Not visible to Lists (??)
 4. Visible to List (??)

Not really sure about the last two, will have to test it out later.