# How NOT to see updates in my Facebook feed from people in my Restricted list?

Tags: facebook, friend-list

I use Facebook lists a lot, including the Restricted list. Based on my understanding, people in Restricted can only see what's public on my profile (i.e., just like none-friends can). All good.

**What I want:**
I don't want to see updates from my "Restricted" friends in my news feed.

**What happens:** Yet, their status updates keep appearing in my feed.

**I tried:** Changing the settings of the Restricted list via the "Manage List" dropdown menu. I unchecked all the types of updates. But it doesn't work. Strange.

[image]

Does someone have a solution??

I am left needing to manually Unsbuscribe from each person individually. In fact, when the update of a "Restricted" friend appears in my feed, and I open the Subscription menu (by clicking the arrow on the right of their post), I can see that I am still subscribed to them ("Most Updates" is checked by default).

[image]

**So, can we really control subscriptions at the list level?**

Before you ask, these Restricted friends are NOT in another list. Even if they were, the [most restrictive list should prevail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18776/prioritize-facebook-privacy-between-lists-that-are-locked-and-not-locked). But again, they are not.

Answer (score 2):

In order to not see updates from people you have placed on your restricted list you'll have to go to their profile, mouse over "Subscribed" and then select "Unsubscribe".

If you go to a Friend's profile and the word "Subscribe" is there you aren't subscribed to any of their posts, so none will be coming through on your newsfeed.

Comment: It's exactly what I did, I unchecked everything, and it doesn't work for me. I still see these updates in my feed. Does it work for you??

Comment: Ahh, I found the flaw. Unsetting the posts in the list only affect viewing that list's updates. The only way to not see the updates from people on your restricted list is to individually set the subscriptions to that friend to "unsubscribe" I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: That's what it seems, yes. It's what I had found too. But it wasn't intuitive to me so I was wondering if it was even normal (i.e., designed this way vs. bug). So you're saying it is designed this way. Did you find confirmation from another source, or did you figure it out yourself? Thanks anyway! Disappointing answer, but useful nonetheless :)